# Weakly stationary time series questions

Tags: time-series, self-study, confidence-interval, stationarity

> Say I have the following model: $y_t = 0.5y_{t−1} +x_t +v_{1t}$, and $x_t = 0.5x_{t−1} +v_{2t}$, where both $v_{1t}$ and $v_{2t}$ follow IID normal distribution ∼ (0,1). The following statements are either true or false...
>
> (i) The time series $y_t$ is weakly stationary.
>
> (ii) The unconditional variance of $y_t$ is larger than the conditional one-step ahead variance.
>
> (iii) The path of forecasts for $y_{t+i}$ conditional on the information available at time $t$ will be oscillatory but it will eventually converge to 0.1.
>
> (iv) If a sample of 1000 observations were simulated from this model for $y_t$, then at least five values will be expected to be larger than 6.
>
> (v) The upper bound for the 95 percent conditional 1-step ahead confidence interval for $y_t$ is 2.

1. True, because the unconditional moments of $y_t$ do not depend on time?
2. I think this is false... that it can be smaller or larger, but I am not sure, could someone please explain this to me? How do I compute conditional means and variances for this type of model? I'm not quite sure I understand this...

Is the one step ahead conditional mean $E[y_{t+1}|y_t,x_t]=0.5y_t+0.5x_t$?

3. I also think this is false... I think the forecasts will converge to zero?
4. I have no idea where to start with this question, so any help would be appreciated. What is this question asking?
5. I assume I just calculate confidence interval in the usual way using conditional mean and variance? How do I compute the conditional one step ahead variance for $y_t$?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: This thread now has the tag and meets our requirements. I think it should stay open.

Comment: Does anybody have any hints for part (iv) as it is the only one which I have no idea about and I have been working on this problem for days and getting nowhere with it...

Comment: Also, what type of model is this? Does it have a specific name?